# Node.js quick canvas to webp

Tags: node.js, base64, webp

If you look at this code webp out-performs png and jpg by alot

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);

var webp = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp"); // Chrome only?
var png  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var jpg  = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

console.log(webp.length, webp); //  263 byte
console.log(png.length, png);   // 1918 byte
console.log(jpg.length, jpg);   // 1938 byte

document.body.appendChild(new Image).src = webp;
document.body.appendChild(new Image).src = png;
document.body.appendChild(new Image).src = jpg;
</script>
```

I am using the node module https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Which does not support webp but, it does simulate the canvas element

What I think I need would be a wrapper around this canvas to do

```
wrapper(canvas).toDataURL('image/webp');
```

As I have found out on many attempts that converting a base64 png image into webp from png is just poor speed wise.

> webp would be ideal size to transport via websockets quickly. If webp is not supported then I would fallback to png and the user will have a slower experience.

---

Original Question:

In node.js I need a way to convert a string from base64 png to base64 webp.

> I say string because of the nature of my application. Were I to save these particular images then convert them (there are some npm modules that convert image 'files') my server would be filled up with images as these images are suppose to be temporary and on-the-fly for each user, each user gets new about 100 new images when ever they move the page.

In node canvas `canvas.toDataURL('image/webp')` is not supported only image/png

Answer (score 2):

First export as image/png, then convert to webp. There's no other way unless you build nodeJS yourself with your own modifications (complex!). To convert a png image to webp, use a library like https://github.com/lovell/sharp or https://github.com/Intervox/node-webp and clean up the source image after converting is done.

Currently, only Chrome supports exporting canvas contents directly to webp.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
sharp(canvas.toBuffer()).toFormat(sharp.format.webp).toBuffer(function(e,webpbuffer){
                    var webpDataURL='data:image/webp;base64,'+webpbuffer.toString('base64');
                    });
```

And I don't have to save any files to do it. I can create the image with node-canvas then send the image to the client.

Comment: Don't use this suggestion! after a lot of testing this method is slower than transporting pngs as the extra conversion time added to the web socket transport time out weighs transporting larger pngs